# How to break a long expression in the denominator of a fraction?

Tags: equations, amsmath, mathtools

I used the split command to break my equation but I receive the error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l. \end {split}
```

The code in `.tex` file is as follows:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5} 
\begin{split} 
A =1-&\frac{h_{FS}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{FS} +h_{F}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{F} + h_{UNC}p_{I}p_{UN}}{h_{G}+h_{V}+p_{I}(h_{I}+h_{DMC}p_{DM}+h_{UNC}p_{UN}+h_{UMC}p_{UM}+h_{DNC}p_{DN}+h_{FS}p_{DN}p_{FS} +\\
 &h_{GD}p_{DN}p_{GD} + h_{F}p_{DN}p_{F})}  
\end {split}
\end{equation}
```

Actually, I can see the produced equation in the PDF and it's
 correct but this error exists. I want to submit my source file to a journal, but the PDF cannot be generated in the submission process. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: \begin{equation}\label{eq:5} \begin{split} A =1-&\frac{h_{FS}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{FS} +h_{F}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{F} + h_{UNC}p_{I}p_{UN}}{h_{G}+h_{V}+p_{I}(h_{I}+h_{DMC}p_{DM}+h_{UNC}p_{UN}+h_{UMC}p_{UM}+h_{DNC}p_{DN}+h_{FS}p_{DN}p_{FS} +\\ &h_{GD}p_{DN}p_{GD} + h_{F}p_{DN}p_{F})}
\end {split} \end{equation}

Comment: You can't split the second part of a `\frac` on two line unless you put it inside something like a `\parbox`

Answer (score 29):

You could use the `\splitfrac` instruction of the `mathtools` package to split the long denominator into two lines. Note that you needn't employ a `split` environment in this case. I've increased the size of the round parentheses used in the denominator (via `\bigl` and `\bigr` instructions) to give them a bit more visibility. I would also typeset all subscript terms  in math-roman instead of the standard (math) italics.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools builds on and extends amsmath package
\newcommand\vn[1]{^{}_{\mathrm{#1}}} % (subscript-level) variable names
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:5}
A = 1-\frac{h\vn{FS}p\vn{I}p\vn{DN}p\vn{FS}
           +h\vn{F}p\vn{I}p\vn{DN}p\vn{F} + h\vn{UNC}p\vn{I}p\vn{UN}}{%
\splitfrac{\textstyle % turn off cramped denom. style
            h\vn{G}+h\vn{V}+p\vn{I} \bigl( h\vn{I}+h\vn{DMC}p\vn{DM}
           +h\vn{UNC}p\vn{UN}+h\vn{UMC}p\vn{UM}}
          {\textstyle % turn off cramped denom. style
           +h\vn{DNC}p\vn{DN}+h\vn{FS}p\vn{DN}p\vn{FS}
           +h\vn{GD}p\vn{DN}p\vn{GD} + h\vn{F}p\vn{DN}p\vn{F} \bigr)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18):

The other answers give you what you wanted (+1 to both), but for what it's worth, I would consider tackling this using local definitions to make it a little easier to read

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % mathtools builds on and extends amsmath package
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eq:5} 
    A = 1-\frac{f(h,p)}{g(h,p)}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
    f(h,p) & =h_{FS}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{FS} +h_{F}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{F} + h_{UNC}p_{I}p_{UN}                                    \\
    g(h,p) & =h_{G}+h_{V}+p_{I}\left( h_{I}+h_{DMC}p_{DM}+h_{UNC}p_{UN}+h_{UMC}p_{UM}\right.                         \\
           & \phantom{ {}= } + \left. h_{DNC}p_{DN}+h_{FS}p_{DN}p_{FS} +h_{GD}p_{DN}p_{GD} + h_{F}p_{DN}p_{F}\right) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the present case, the `\left( ... \right.` and `\left. ... \right)` don't actually increase the size of the parentheses. It may be better to use `\big` statements instead.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the feedback; I view `\big` as a bit too manual though, perhaps that's just me :)

Comment: Great answer, Chris! `:)` I think this is the cleanest way to tackle this expression. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda thanks a lot :) I always appreciate your positivity :)

Answer (score 11):

Here's a TeXy way (`amsmath` will nag though if you're using it, IIRC.):

```
A = 1-{h_{FS}p_Ip_{DN}p_{FS} +h_Fp_Ip_{DN}p_F + h_{UNC}p_Ip_{UN}
  \over\displaystyle{
  h_G+h_V+p_I\big( h_I+h_{DMC}p_{DM}+h_{UNC}p_{UN}+h_{UMC}p_{UM}
  \atop\quad
  {}+h_{DNC}p_{DN}+h_{FS}p_{DN}p_{FS}+h_{GD}p_{DN}p_{GD}+h_Fp_{DN}p_F\big)}}
```

[image]

Comment: Even if it doesn't change anything in this case, I'd use `\bigl` and `\bigr` instead of `\big`.

Answer (score 10):

If you place the denominator of the `\frac` with a `\parbox` then you can have a new line in it:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5} 
A =1-\frac{h_{FS}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{FS} +h_{F}p_{I}p_{DN}p_{F} + h_{UNC}p_{I}p_{UN}}{\parbox{4.2in}{$h_{G}+h_{V}+p_{I}(h_{I}+h_{DMC}p_{DM}+h_{UNC}p_{UN}+h_{UMC}p_{UM}+h_{DNC}p_{DN} +$ \\
 \hspace*{2.1cm}$h_{FS}p_{DN}p_{FS} + h_{GD}p_{DN}p_{GD} + h_{F}p_{DN}p_{F})$}} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```