# How to put several lines in the numerator of a fraction?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

When I use \\ it breaks the frac layout.
Now I come up with the following solution:

```
$$\frac{{O\vdash e_1:T_1 \atop O[T_1/x]\vdash e_2:T_2}}{O\vdash (let\ ((x e_1))\ e_2):T_2}$$
```

But it gives two lines with smaller font, and I need all 3 of them to be equal-sized.

#### UPDATED:

Also it will be needed to place more than two (three or four) lines into the numerator of a frac.

Comment: `$$` is obsolete use `\[\]` instead, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to.

Comment: See also [How to break a long expression in the denominator of a fraction?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74283) My recommendation: Don't do it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use the `aligned` sub-environment from `amsmath`"

```
\[
\frac{\begin{aligned}
      O&\vdash e_1:T_1 \\ O[T_1/x]&\vdash e_2:T_2
      \end{aligned}}%
  {O\vdash (let\ ((x e_1))\ e_2):T_2}
\]
```

(your question ended abruptly, so there may have been more specifications that i wasn't aware of.)

if you wish these lines to be centered, then use `gathered` rather than `aligned` (and omit the `&`s).

both `aligned` and `gathered` can accommodate any number of lines, even more than four, although it seems to me that this probably gets too complicated.

remember that the baseline is still relative to the math axis (which is coincident with the fraction rule), so all extra lines will continue to rise above the rest of the displayed expression, and if that part of the expression is in parentheses, the parentheses will be unattractively empty below the line.

Comment: Instead of this, `splitfrac` command from `mathtools` is here for the occasion. `\frac{\splitfrac{}{}}{}`. And `\splitdfrac{}{}` if you want it in displaymath.

Comment: How to align them by centre, instead of right border?

Answer (score 0):

Package mathtools provides a proper command, I will give an example soon

[Update}

Here goes the unswer posted by Manuel:
\splitfrac{〈numer〉}{〈denom〉} is what you are wanting to. Then:

```
\[
   \frac{\splitfrac{O \vdash e_1 : T_1}{O[T_1/x] \vdash e_2 : T_2}}
   {O \vdash (let\ ((x e_1)) \ e_2) : T_2} 
\]
```

Comment: `\splitfrac{〈numer〉}{〈denom〉}` is what you are wanting to. Then: `\[ \frac{\splitfrac{O \vdash e_1 : T_1}{O[T_1/x] \vdash e_2 : T_2}}{O \vdash (let\ ((x e_1)) \ e_2) : T_2} \]` should be the correct way.